# Problem with working directory and web scraping

Tags: r, working-directory

I am working on a simple web scraping script when the sapply function is giving me problems with the working directory.
I state that a few days ago I changed username on windows 10 and I think this is partly the problem. Below is the code:

```
library(string)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)


cbindPad <- function(...){
  args <- list(...)
  n <- sapply(args,nrow)
  mx <- max(n)
  pad <- function(x, mx){
    if (nrow(x) < mx){
      nms <- colnames(x)
      padTemp <- matrix(0, mx - nrow(x), ncol(x))
      colnames(padTemp) <- nms
      if (ncol(x)==0) {
        return(padTemp)
      } else {
        return(rbind(x,padTemp))
      }
    }
    else{
      return(x)
    }
  }
  rs <- lapply(args,pad,mx)
  return(do.call(cbind,rs))
}



get.SKU <-  function(link_prod){
  page_prod <- read_html(link_prod)
  cod.sku <- page_prod %>% html_nodes(".sku") %>% html_text() 
  return(cod.sku)
}

g <- c("notebook")
page <- 1
trova.gross <- function(page, prodotto) {
  link <- paste0("https://www.galagross.com/page/",page,"/?s=",prodotto,"&post_type=product&product_cat=0")
  
  webpage <- read_html(link)
  
  links_prod <-  webpage %>% html_nodes(".product-title a") %>%  html_attr("href")
  
  name <- tibble( prodotto= prodotto , title <- webpage %>% html_nodes(".product-title a") %>% html_text() )

  name.2_ul <-webpage %>% html_nodes(".woocommerce-product-details__short-description ul") %>% html_text()  %>% tibble()
  
  sku <- data.frame(unlist(sapply(links_prod, FUN=get.SKU , USE.NAMES = FALSE)))
  
  tecno.data <- rbind(tecno.data, cbindPad(name, name.2_ul, sku))
  
}
trova.gross(page = 1, prodotto = g)
```

And here's the mistake. What can I do? Thank you in advance for your help

```
Error: '' does not exist in current working directory ('C:/Program Files/RStudio')
```

Comment: Hi Stefano, your previous version of this question was closed because it was not possible to reproduce your code, and the same problem appears here. We are not able to help you without further detail.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66802519/problems-with-web-scarping-and-working-directory

Comment: What I would suggest is going through your custom functions line by line to find where the error is occurring. It could be in how you create the `trova.gross()` function. We simply won't be able to solve your problem without further details.

Comment: Hi @Phil, if you ask me what details you need I will give them to you right away.
 And I did the same thing in the previous question but it was closed. And it was really useless. 
If you need some more details ask. I am here first to work and second to learn from people more experienced than 
me like you. Thanks, I'm looking forward to your feedbac

Comment: This is already a more proactive attitude. You ask me for more details and I will provide them to you. in particular, the find.gross () function must provide me with the complete list of some notebooks on the page, whether they have the description or not and must enter the page of each individual product to find the SKU code

Comment: @ Phil I think the problem lies precisely in sku. I tried using map_df () from the purrr package but I always get the same error. Thanks for the support you are giving me

Comment: When you create `links_prod` inside your `trova.gross` function, add `links_prod <- links_prod[links_prod != ""]` and try again.